Swift addingPercentEncoding result not the same when input the same paramaters
      let path1 = "[path:test]"
      var set = CharacterSet()
      set.formUnion(.urlPathAllowed)

      let encodedPath1 = path1.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: set)
      let encodedPath2 = path1.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)

      print("Encoded Path 1: \(String(describing: encodedPath1))")
      print("Encoded Path 2: \(String(describing: encodedPath2))")

the print is(: is not encoded in the first.)
Encoded Path 1: Optional("%5Bpath:test%5D")
Encoded Path 2: Optional("%5Bpath%3Atest%5D")


Only the second encoding is valid according to RFC 3986. A colon is allowed in a relative path (which your string is), except in the first path component (i.e. before the first slash).
addingPercentEncoding handles the built-in URL-related character classes differently from the random character classes you create in your code. The character classes you create in your code cannot encode complicated logic like "colon is allowed unless it is before the first slash", even if it contains the same characters as a built-in URL character class.
You can see how this works by looking at the _CFStringCreateByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters function in swift-corelibs-foundation repository. This isn't exactly what is run on Apple platforms, but it's a good reference.
This function calls GetURLPredefinedCharacterSet to see if the passed in character set is one of the built-in ones. Crucially, GetURLPredefinedCharacterSet does a pointer comparison with the built-in character sets:
for ( result = 0; result < kURLAllowedCharacterSetIllegal; ++result ) {
    // yes, I really want a pointer comparison because some of the sURLAllowedCharacterSets have the same bitmaps
    if ( characterSet == sURLAllowedCharacterSets[result] ) {
        break;
    }
}

It will not find your set in the sURLAllowedCharacterSets array, so it will return kURLAllowedCharacterSetIllegal, and _CFStringCreateByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters will treat your set as a regular character set with no special meaning, and not escape the colon, since the colon character is in the set.
If you use the built-in .urlPathAllowed, _CFStringCreateByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters will go down a different path, and reach here, where the special handling is done.
We can see that in the else branch of if (pastSlash), it explicitly disallows colons:
Boolean allowed = (ch <= 127) && (ch != ';') && (ch != ':') && ((sURLAllowedCharacters[ch] & allowedMask) != 0);

whereas in the if branch, there is no && (ch != ';').
